# Multi Select Parameter not diplaying records when display all is selected because one of the categories has no records

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a parameter for a report called Category, it is a multi select parameter  with (select all) category 1, category 2, category 3.

```
@Category NVARCHAR(10)    
Select ...
from dbo.item i

INNER JOIN dbo.ItemCategory AS ic ON i.Category = ic.Code

AND i.Category = @Category
```

There are items that are in category 1 but the other two do not have items in those categories yet, they will in the future.

When i select the select all in the Category parameter instead of showing me just the category 1 records it diplays nothing, the only way that it will display something is if i select the category 1 check box alone. how do i fix it so that it will display the category items from category 1 when select all is selected?

Comment: Can you please provide us the DDL with some sample data ? even 3 rows will be fine so that it's easier for us to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, the parameter was returning category1,category2,category3 all as one string so i needed to split the string so that the individual categories were being passed and not as one giant string.

```
  AND i.Category IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitString(@Category, ','))
```

---

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
CREATE  FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
(
@List nvarchar(4000),
@token nvarchar(5)
)  
RETURNS @RtnValue table 
(
--Id int identity(1,1),
Value nvarchar(100)
)  
AS  
BEGIN

SET @List = RTRIM(LTRIM(@List))
IF @List <> '' 
BEGIN
    WHILE (CHARINDEX(@token, @List)>0)
    BEGIN 

        INSERT INTO @RtnValue (value)
        SELECT Value = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List,1,CHARINDEX          (@token,@List)-1))) 

        SET @List = SUBSTRING(@List,CHARINDEX(@token,@List)+LEN(@token),LEN(@List))

    END 

    INSERT INTO @RtnValue (Value)
    SELECT Value = LTRIM(RTRIM(@List))
END

RETURN
END
GO
```